# Replace query parameters with JSON body in Spring Boot PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: json, spring-boot, query-string, spring-repositories

I'm using **PagingAndSortingRepository** from Spring Boot.

Is it possible to receive parameters from http body (json) instead of receiving them by query parameters (@Param).

Example:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
  List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
  Person findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

I'm Looking for an alternative of `@Param("name") String name` so that the value gets extracted from JSON-Body instead of the query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my mistake was not to think about it in depth. It doesn't make any sense to use body payload for querying data from a REST resoucre.

Think of a link which one user (A) wants to share with another user (B) (e.g. by sending it via email). The query parameters would be missing and so the link wouldn't represent the site from user's A point of view. The only way to share the sites information by link is to append the query parameters to the link itself.